# Convert french accent to specific encoding in PHP

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

In php, what function can I use to convert the text 'pétition' to 'p%E9tition'.

I have tried with `uft8_encode` and `uft8_decode` with no success.

Comment: Don't you mean `p%C3%A9tition` ? `urlencode('pétition');`

Answer (score 1):

%E9 is an *URL* encoded escape character. You can achieve this by `urlecode($string)`.

If you want *HTML* escaping, you can either use `htmlentities($string)` (more encoding) or `htmlspecialchars($string)` (less encoding).

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with UTF-8 strings, you will need to decode the string (ie. with [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)) before encoding with [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to be used in a query part of a URL.

```
print_r( urlencode(utf8_decode('pétition')) );
// p%E9tition
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a look at htmlentities.
This [link](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) can help